# Открыть/закрыть боковое меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть кнопка при нажатии на которую происходит открытие бокового меню. А как сделать чтоб при клике на эту же кнопку меню закрылось.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-menu").mmenu({
        navbar: {
            title : "Меню"
        }
    });

    var API = $("#my-menu").data( "mmenu" );

    $('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        API.open();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно проверять наличие класса open и в зависимости от этого открывать или закрывать:

```
var API = $("#my-menu").data( "mmenu" );

$('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    if ($(this).hasClass('open'))
    {
        API.open();
    }
    else
    {
        API.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Мысль такая же пришла сразу, но не знал как проверить существование класса. Ещё раз спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Сложно дать точный ответ, не зная как конкретно сделано меню. Можно попробовать воспользоваться функцией [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) или [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/):

```
$('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
    $("#my-menu").toggle();
});
```